# Nuget install within Visual Studio 2017 skips content folder named "Windows"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, package

I created a nuget package containing a content folder named "Windows".  The folder structure is as follows:

```
|- package.nuspec
|- content
   |- first.cs.pp
   |- Windows
      |- second.cs.pp
```

The package is created successfully from the command line using Nuget.exe  4.7.0.5148.  I verified that all files were correctly included in the .nupkg file.  However, when I install this package in a Visual Studio project, the entire Windows folder is excluded.  If I change the 's' to a 'z' (Windowz) it works just fine and second.cs is installed.

I did a -verbose install of the package, and the Windows folder isn't even mentioned.  Is "Windows" a reserved folder name for nuget?

The contents of the package and the package itself are published to [github](https://github.com/wimpleshapers/SOPackageWindows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is "Windows" a reserved folder name for nuget?

The short answer is yes. I have download your nuget package and open it with NuGet Package Explorer (You can get it from Microsoft store). Then I noticed that the windows folder is marked as Target Frameworks:

[image]

If we change `Windows` to other word, it will become a common folder, which can be add to the project:

[image]

**Then** I search the nuget official document [Target frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks), found that the `Windows` is indeed a reserved field as a **Supported frameworks**:

[image]

Hope this helps .

Comment: Is there a way to tell nuget I want a literal "Windows" folder, or must the first level folder always be the framework?

Comment: @Dan, you can submit your request [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues). And the first level of the folder does not need to be the framework

Answer (score 0):

A [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would have been helpful, or at least mentioning which version of NuGet.exe you used (did you try downloading the latest?). I created the same directory structure you listed, and I used the [sample at the top of the .nuspec docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/nuspec#general-form-and-schema) for the contents of the .nuspec file, filling in only the 4 mandatory elements it lists and adding absolutely nothing else. Here is my output:

```
C:\git\test\pptest> nuget pack -verbosity detailed
NuGet Version: 4.9.2.5706
Attempting to build package from 'pptest.nuspec'.

Id: pptest
Version: 1.0.0
Authors: zivkan
Description: testing
Dependencies: None

Added file '[Content_Types].xml'.
Added file '_rels/.rels'.
Added file 'content/first.cs.pp'.
Added file 'content/Windows/second.cs.pp'.
Added file 'package/services/metadata/core-properties/373c9fa8025c4ee49217861072d632ae.psmdcp'.
Added file 'pptest.nuspec'.

Successfully created package 'C:\git\test\pptest\pptest.1.0.0.nupkg'.
```

So, all I can say is "it works for me".

For reference, here's my complete .nuspec file, not that I imagine it adds anything useful to this answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <!-- Required elements-->
        <id>pptest</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <description>testing</description>
        <authors>zivkan</authors>

        <!-- Optional elements -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </metadata>
    <!-- Optional 'files' node -->
</package>
```

Comment: I have updated the original question with more details and version information, along with an example.  It was not obvious from my original post that the problem was encountered in Visual Studio.